# Fetch maximum possibility value while group by in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have table as following in my database

```
----------------------
id | keyword    | location 
----------------------
1  | Test-New   |    1
2  | Test       |    1
3  | Test       |    1
4  | Test       |    1
----------------------
```

I need to get results based on location so I used group by

```
select keyword, location ,count(*) as count from table_name group by location
```

Now i get following results

```
----------------------------
keyword    | Location |  count
---------------------------
Test-New   |    1     |   4
---------------------------
```

but I want most popular keyword for each location and count of each location. In this example I need **Test** instead of **Test-New** for location **1** (Because in the actual table Test appeared 3 times and Test-New appeared 1 time).

So I need results like this

```
--------------------------
keyword | Location |  count
--------------------------
Test    |    1     |   4
--------------------------
```

Comment: Where does count = 3 come from?

Comment: Total number of location 1 is 3

Comment: So you want the total number of keywords in each location, and the most popular keyword at each location?

Comment: I dont want total number of keywords. Want most popular keyword at each location.

Comment: In that case the count is 2, not 3

Comment: No location 1 has 3 count.

Comment: Not according to your definition "I don't want total number of keywords"

Comment: Total number of keywords = 'Test1' + 'Test' + 'Test' = 3. Most popular keyword = 'Test' + 'Test' = 2

Comment: yes i don't want keyword count. Need total count of each location with popular keyword.

Comment: I thin you should try again to clarify your question, summarising the comments above.

Comment: I want most popular keyword for each location. So from my example location 1 keyword Test, Location 2 keyword Test2

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Find popular keyword in each location using mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983620/). Posting the same question several times and under different identities is not at all a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working properly ......enjoy RaGu bhai

```
   SELECT  
temp.keyword,temp.location,SUM(temp.TotalLocation) AS COUNT
 FROM (SELECT 
    keyword,location,
    COUNT(location) AS TotalLocation
  FROM
    `test` 
  GROUP BY location,keyword ORDER BY TotalLocation DESC)
  temp GROUP BY location;
```

[demo execute here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9570e/4)

Comment: let me know what exactly do you want ?? i could not figure you out what you want to say

Comment: I want most popular keyword for each location and count of each location. So from my example location '1' count '3' keyword 'Test', Location '2' count '1' keyword Test2

Comment: if location "1" have multiple keyword what will do in this case suggest me

Comment: location 1 has test1 and test

Comment: yes location 1 has test1 and test. In this case we have to find popular keyword. That means test appeared 2 times in location 1 and test1 appeared only 1 time, so we have to take test as the keyword for location 1.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this query:

```
select keyword ,count(keyword) as TotalKeyword from table_name group by location
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT keyword
           , location
           , COUNT(*) cnt 
        FROM my_table 
       GROUP 
          BY keyword
           , location
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT keyword
            , MAX(cnt) max_cnt
         FROM 
            ( SELECT keyword
                   , location
                   , COUNT(*) cnt 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP 
                  BY keyword
                   , location
            ) x 
        GROUP 
           BY keyword
     ) b
    ON b.keyword = a.keyword
   AND b.max_cnt = a.cnt;
```

Comment: No. In this query I will get two different results for Test and Test1 for location 1.

Comment: Perhaps you should try again to clarify what it is you want.

Comment: I need total count of location with maximum number of keyword which related to that location. In my table Location 1 has Test keyword 2 times and Test1 keyword 1 time, So i need Test as the keyword for location 1.

Comment: I didn't understand that statement the first time. Repeating it hasn't helped.

Comment: Edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is a bit confusion, are you asking for something like this ?

```
select *,
count(location) as location_count
from test1 group by location, keyword
```

Comment: No. I want most popular keyword for each location and count of each location.